# Not sending data with AJAX to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem with catching AJAX data with PHP and send it to the database. Site is on the WordPress platform.

I have checked for the errors with `mysqli_error` but there nothing happened. Console not showing any error, just show there is `console.log data from the ajax, so the ajax work.

Here is what I have tried so far.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
         'creditCardValue':creditCardValue,
         'creditCardValueCvc':creditCardValueCvc,
         'phoneNumberForm':phoneNumberForm
    }
});
```

Here is a PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button'])) { // button name from html
    $creditCardValue = $_POST['creditCardValue'];
    $creditCardValueCvc = $_POST['creditCardValueCvc'];
    $phoneNumberForm = $_POST['phoneNumberForm'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO validations(credit_card_number, credit_card_cvc, phone_number) ";
    $query .= "VALUES ({$creditCardValue}, '{$creditCardValueCvc}', '{$phoneNumberForm}' ) ";
    $create_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
?>
```

I need to send all these data to the database so I can later call them and displayed them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way is this failing?  You don't examine the value of `$create_post_query`.  If it's `false` then you need to use `mysqli_error` to check for errors.  Your code is also wide open to SQL injection, so you could be executing *anything*.  Also, are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  "It doesn't work" doesn't really tell us anything about the problem.

Comment: Thanks on the quick reply. I have checked for the errors with ```mysqli_error``` but there nothing happened. Console not showing any error, just show there is console log data from the ajax, so the ajax work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the check for `$_POST['button']` as this is not sent with the AJAX data. If you want to check if it's an AJAX call then just check that one of the values has been POSTed:

```
if (isset($_POST['creditCardValue'])) { ...
```

Comment: To add more, AJAX doesn't automatically send HTML variables like a form does with the post method. The only variables that are sent are those in the `data: {}` section of the AJAX call

Comment: After I've refactored the code in a file everything is worked fine. I've removed the `isset($_POST)` as you've said and it's work perfect.